# How to use LINQ instead of a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I want to convert the foreach loop into a linq query because `itemList` can have a lot of values and it is time consuming to iterate over each value in that list. Can linq be used to accomplish this?

```
string fileAsString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
Match match = Regex.Match(filePath, regx.ToString());

while (match.Success)
{
    string itemToReplace = match.Groups["part"].Value;

    //Use linq instead of the commented out area
    //
    //foreach (var item in itemList)
    //{
    //    if (itemToReplace == macro.Name)
    //    {
    //        fileAsString = fileAsString.Replace(match.Value, item.Value);
    //    }
    //}
    //

    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Linq doesn't get rid of the loop.

Comment: What makes you think Linq would result in faster execution?

Comment: linq wouldnt be faster

Comment: Where does `fileAsString` come from?

Comment: To do a `x2 = f(x1)`, for x1..xn operation in LINQ maps to an [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx) (or Fold). However, it would likely be better to use a Regular Expression with Match Evaluator to handle the file replacements.

Comment: LINQ isn't magic. If you've got many replacements to perform, that's going to take time. Just making your code use LINQ won't make those replacements any faster.

Comment: What is the type of itemList?

Comment: The inner loop confuses me. Why is it `fileAsString.Replace(match.Value, item.Value)` and not `fileAsString.Replace(item.Value, match.Value)`? The only reason for the former is for recursive replacements while the latter means "replace any of these items with the match" (in which case the outer loop is confuses me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Aggregate LINQ method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx) (aka a [fold/reduce operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))) does an `r_{n+1} = f(r_n, x_n)`, for n in `[0..len)`, and evaluates to `r_{n+1}`.

Applying a fold over the Replace operation<sup>1</sup>;

```
fileAsString = itemList.Aggregate(fileAsString,
    (acc, item) => acc.Replace(match.Value, item.Value));
```

An Aggregate can also be applied over the outer loop if using `Regex.Matches`. However, using LINQ *won't* change the time complexity or make the code run faster - Replace is called the *same* number of times.

[Note: I looked at the code again and am not confused why the repeated replacement even occurs; the following may not apply. Should the arguments to Replace be the *other* way?]

If performance is an issue, it would likely be better to use a regular expression [Replace with a match evaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle the file replacements. That is, create a pattern matching all the items, as minimally as possible - it can be as specific as `a|b|c` or more general. Then inside the match elevator use a Dictionary to look up the replacement value.

---

<sup>1</sup> The conditional check can be moved *outside* the inner loop because the expression is fixed during the loop. While this won't affect the running time I've done so [out of preference and] because it makes the LINQ slightly simpler.